# How do I check if the text between two closed tags XML exists or not in minidom-

Tags: python, xml, minidom

My sample xmlis like this:

```
<name></name>
<salary>19099</salary>
```

How do I check if the text between two closed tags i.e "`<name>`" exists or not in minidom.

What to do if it is blank?

If the text doesn't exists, it should continue with next iterartion.

Answer (score 1):

You should have provided us with an XML sample data to work with. Otherwise, here is a dirty example:

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> s = '<example>19099</example>'
>>> xmldom = minidom.parseString(s)
>>> elts = xmldom.getElementsByTagName('example')
>>> for elt in elts:
...     if elt.childNodes[0].nodeValue == '19099':
...             print 'It exists'
... 
It exists
```

**Update:**

The tags you provided did **not** appear before I formatted your question. So here is the answer: you can check if there are child nodes relative to the `<name>` tags:

```
>>> s2 = '<name></name>'
>>> xmldom = minidom.parseString(s2)
>>> elements = xmldom.getElementsByTagName('name')
>>> for element in elements:
...     if len(element.childNodes)>0:
...             print 'There is a name text there'
... 
>>>
```

But this depends on how your XML data is really structured. My solution works if the XML data is as you shared it here: `<name></name>`.